# PowerShell - Cannot remove profile created with Enter-PSSession unless winrm service is stopped?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

I am using the remove-profile script from here http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-Profile-787d9188 to remove profiles which is working great until an interesting problem I came across is not letting me remove a profile. When a profile is created by a user logging in with Enter-PSSession the profile cannot be removed until the winrm service is stopped. Does anyone know what causes this or know how to get around this so I don't have to stop the winrm service? Here is a screenshot of what it looks like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBnQ0.jpg

Comment: Do these users close the ps session by exit, Exit-PSSession, Remove-PSSession or does the session still exists? Also note there is an IdleTimeout

Comment: The session is closed by closing the cmd/PowerShell console. This is some kind of file lock problem or problem with the session still being active. Get-PSSession does not seem to work so I don't know how to view active sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell remote session were probably not closed correctly. Either make sure they are closed correctly (Remove-PSSession or Exit-PSSession) or try to remove them with something like below (PowerShell v3 and higher, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846417/getting-all-open-ps-sessions-on-a-remote-server-from-new-console-window)).

```
Get-PSSession -ComputerName MyServerName | Remove-PSSession
```

Comment: Get-PSSession never seems to work? it never displays any sessions information.

Comment: Do you use PowerShell version 3 or higher? Please check with $PSVersionTable

Comment: No, I use the default PS that comes in Windows. I think it is still 2.0?

Comment: You need PowerShell v3 to have that line working as expected. Different Windows versions come with different PowerShell versions. Check $PSVersionTable

Comment: The get-pssession commands are there but they just don't work? Anyways, this script/program I am working on needs to work on any version of PS so people do not need to install anything when they go to run it. I want it to work "out of the box" for people. So, what are my options to resolve this problem now?